# Can't update item in database [sqlite]

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Can't find an error in code. I'm sure, that there might be some problems with ID's. Maybe queries are wrong. Kinda new to this stuff.

**MyDBHelper**

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String EditTextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
                Task t = new Task(EditTextValue);
                dbHandler.updateTask(t);


                if (dbHandler.updateTask(t) == true){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "naah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                  displayTaskList();
             }
```

Update function:

```
 public boolean updateTask(Task t){
    boolean result = false;
    String q = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = " + t.getID();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        String q2 = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COLUMN_TASK + " = "
                + t.getTASK() + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = " + t.getID();
        db.execSQL(q2);
        result = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

Task class:

```
public class Task {
private int _id;
private String _task;

public Task() {}
public Task(String task){
    this._task = task;
}
public Task (int id, String task){
    this._id = id;
    this._task = task;
}

// SETS&GETS
public void setID(int id) {
    this._id = id;
}
public int getID() {
    return this._id;
}
public void setTASK(String task){
    this._task = task;
}
public String getTASK(){
    return this._task;
}
}
```

**Mainactivity:**

```
// To detect which list item is selected (by ID)
private long _id;
public void setID(long id) { this._id = id; }
public long getID() { return this._id; }

// Attaches a long click listener to the listview
private void setupListViewListener() {
    lvTasks.setOnItemLongClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                               View item, int pos, long id) {
                    item1.setVisible(true); item2.setVisible(true); item3.setVisible(true); // Showing all buttons
                    setID(id); //Catches the selected items ID
                    return true;
                }

            });
}
```

The problem might be that it mixes up ID's? For instance in Mainactivity the ID I get is selected task (onlongclick), but in Task/MyDBHelper class ID is the newly created task - even though they're not connected(?). Any help would be a great.

Comment: What is your error, if any?  By the way, your current query is building the `WHERE` clause using raw concatenation, leaving the query vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should parameterize the queries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can u give me a hint? Problem is - nothing happens. I need to edit task, but it leaves it untouched and the problem is, the update function returns false (it means, something failed, instead of updating and returning true)

Answer (score 0):

You can use update function like this:

```
 public int updateTask(Task t){
 //i assume you open your db here
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

 //put values that needs to be updated in values with column names and  values
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(COLUMN_TASK,t.getTASK());
 values.put(COLUMN_ID,t.getID());

 // db.update(String table,ContentValues values,String whereClause,String[] whereArguments)
 int result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,COLUMN_ID+"=?"+new String[] {String.ValueOf(t.getID())});
 db.close();
 return result;
 }
```

I guess this solves your problem.

Comment: @Efran Gholapour
     int result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,COLUMN_ID+"=?"+new String[]{t.getID()} );  
updates function require last parameter a String, but you can't have a String array, when t.getID returns int, so it give me a error at that line.

Comment: you can convert int to string like this : String.ValueOf(t.getID). I updated my answer.